# Selenium click() from link text throwing exception on Windows

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver

Using python from command line, I execute the following:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://amazon.com/mp3')
el = driver.find_element_by_link_text('MP3 Downloads : MP3 Songs')
el.click()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.19.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 45, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.19.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 194, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.19.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 153, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.19.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 147, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'current is undefined'
```

I have no idea what "CURRENT" is...
I ran it on a different machine and the error became

```
...Message u'l is undefined'
```

Any suggestions? By the way this only happens for Windows on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue when clicking a button.

You can click it by sending the "space" character:

```
webDriver.FindElement("button_id").SendKeys(" ");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have found workarounds to this with both sending " " as well as "\n"
but I was wondering if you knew what the source of this error was?
Thank you.